# R - Count duplicates values for each row

Tags: r, kappa

I'm working on a data frame that requires to calculate Fleiss's Kappa for inter-rater agreements. I'm using the 'irr' package for that.

Besides that, I need to count, for each observation, how many of raters are in agreement.

My data looks like these:

```
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 1 2 2
3 2 3 2
4 3 3 1
5 4 2 1
```

I'm expecting something like this, , where count stands for number of raters on agreement

```
  a b c count
1 1 1 1 3 
2 1 2 2 2
3 2 3 2 2
4 3 3 1 2
5 4 2 1 0
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `apply(df1, 1, function(x) sum(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)))`

Comment: Or using `table` `apply(df1, 1, function(x) {x1 <- table(x);sum(x1[x1 > 1]) })`

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO, I think your question can be greatly improved if you show what you have already tried so far and tell us where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Hi! I'm a newbie to R language, and I don't know how to do this analysis (even on another software). I've been reading about the 'irr' package, but I have not found what I need. I thought about simply transform the data using functions like ifelse or case_when, with no results. Thanks @akrun, I'll try what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution if your data is in a data frame called `abc`:

```
as.numeric(apply(abc,1,function(x) { 
    ux<-unique(x); 
    tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux)); 
    mode <- ux[tab == max(tab)];
    ifelse(length(mode)==1,length(which(x==mode)),NA_character_);
} ))
```

When you run it gives:

```
[1]  3  2  2  2 NA
```